# Manual memory manager in C# - just a research

Tags: c#, winapi, memory-management

I'm doing some research, and I implemented a simple memory manager system to see how the process behaves, but I noticed that the free method of MemoryHelper class, and the "Marshal.FreeHGlobal" do not realize the free in memory, with possible access the data even after releasing the memory...

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public unsafe static class MemoryHelper
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetProcessHeap();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
        static extern void* HeapAlloc(IntPtr hHeap, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwBytes);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern void* HeapReAlloc(IntPtr hHeap, uint dwFlags, IntPtr lpMem, UIntPtr dwBytes);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool HeapFree(IntPtr hHeap, uint dwFlags, void* lpMem);

        private static uint HEAP_REALLOC_IN_PLACE_ONLY = 0x00000010;
        private static uint HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE = 0x00000001;
        private static uint HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY = 0x00000008;
        private static IntPtr Handle { get; set; } = GetProcessHeap();

        public static void* Malloc(uint size)
        {
            var tmp = HeapAlloc(Handle, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, new UIntPtr(size));
            if (tmp == null)
                throw new Exception("Fail to allocate memory");
            return tmp;
        }

        public static void* Realloc(IntPtr blk, uint newSize)
        {
            var tmp = HeapReAlloc(Handle, HEAP_REALLOC_IN_PLACE_ONLY, blk, new UIntPtr(newSize));
            if (tmp == null)
                throw new Exception("Fail to reallocate memory");
            return tmp;
        }

        public static bool Free(void* blk)
        {
            var ret = HeapFree(Handle, HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, blk);
            if (!ret)
                throw new Exception("Fail to free memory");
            return ret;
        }
    }

    unsafe public class Study
    {
        public Study()
        {
            UsingManualMemoryClass();
            Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(80, '='));
            UsingMarshalClass();
        }

        private static readonly object LockObj = new object();
        public void UsingManualMemoryClass()
        {
            int tamanho = 20;
            int* teste = (int*)MemoryHelper.Malloc((uint)(sizeof(int) * tamanho));

            Random rnd = new Random();
            lock (LockObj)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
                    teste[i] = rnd.Next(0,8000);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(teste[i]);

            MemoryHelper.Free(teste);

            Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(80, '-'));
            for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(teste[i]);
        }

        public void UsingMarshalClass()
        {
            int tamanho = 20;
            int* teste = (int*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int) * tamanho);

            Random rnd = new Random();
            lock (LockObj)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
                    teste[i] = rnd.Next(0, 8000);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(teste[i]);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)teste);

            Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(80, '-'));
            for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(teste[i]);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Study();
        }
    }
}
```

Why this happens?

----- EDIT

I found this article in [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32125/Unmanaged-Arrays-in-C-No-Problem), and I get the C++/CLI code, created a simple DLL with the code and did some changes to use native C runtime to alloc and free memory

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>>

using namespace System;

namespace mm
{
    public ref class Unmanaged abstract sealed
    {
    public:
        generic <typename T> where T : value class
            static void* New(int elementCount)
        {
            return malloc(sizeof(T) * elementCount);
        }

        static void Free(void* unmanagedPointer)
        {
            free(unmanagedPointer);
        }

        generic <typename T> where T : value class
            static void* Resize(void* oldPointer, int newElementCount)
        {
            return realloc(oldPointer, (int)sizeof(T) * newElementCount);
        }
    };
}
```

Using the native C functions to do this, I can't access memory after the free...

Comment: *Why this happens?* In unmanaged languages, you can very well access memory after freeing it. It triggers undefined behavior, but you can do it. Managed languages are supposed to be a solution to this problem, among others.

Comment: I would assume it works simply because that memory hasn't been re-used and overwritten yet. Eventually it would be re-used and you'd get trash data, or exceptions. Generally the same idea as any other pointer-based memory access. C# calls it *unsafe* because you can do silly stuff like this.

Comment: *"How to fix this [...] ?"* - There is nothing broken, so nothing needs to be fixed.

Comment: I did some edits...

Comment: An allocation of 20 * 4 bytes is in general not nearly enough to get the OS to release the address space.  Such small allocations are made from the low-fragmentation heap and releasing it adds the block to the free-block list.  Native C code works differently with a debugger attached, it runs with the debug heap enabled.  Which scrubs the memory block to increase the likelihood of an hard exception when the C program fumbles memory management, a very common C bug.  Getting the same outcome requires setting the _NO_DEBUG_HEAP environment variable to 1.

Comment: The problem with that advice is that the naive reader might decide that the solution to the problem is always to enable the debug heap.

Answer (score 0):

`Marshal.FreeHGlobal` calls the Win32 API function `LocalFree`. If you attempt to access the memory after having called `LocalFree` then you are invoking undefined behaviour. Some possible outcomes of that:

- You might encounter a runtime error.
- You might still be able to access the memory in its previous state.
- You might still be able to access the memory but it has been modified because it has been re-used.
- ...

Pretty much anything can happen and you cannot rely on anything.

Your mistake is to deduce that being able to access the memory after freeing it means that the memory has not been freed. That logical deduction was erroneous.